# cygwin terminal difference (default + "bash prompt here")

Tags: bash, terminal, cygwin

There's a difference in cygwin terminals when I open it directly and when I use chere "Bash Prompt Here".

On the former, if I right click, I get a window with options.

On the later, it does nothing (paste content sometimes). Also the characters are bolder.

Why those differences ?  Where to setup that ?

Comment: Why did I lose a point ?  This is a serious question.

Answer (score 1):

I found out.

When you 'bash prompt here', it is using terminal 'cmd' by default.

You have to do this command :

```
chere -i -t mintty -f
```

It needs the f option to force the change of default terminal.